# Data migration problems 1.9.2.2 to 2.0

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am having some difficulty migrating my pretty standard 1.9.2.2 shop;

Issues:

The migration completes but throws some warnings, per the logs below.

Getting two empty fields on the customer account (possible custom customer attributes from 1.9.2.2 store, that should have been ignored per map file)

One of my attributes (size) on configurable products is asking to be selected prior to saving the configurable product, this is only to be used for generating the simple product. 
(The value of attribute "size_config" must be set)

That same attribute won't hold any changes when saved - for example, to show in column or to be filtered, change the setting from yes to no press save, it reverts back to yes.

Price for configurable products is missing, even tho I can see it in the attribute sets.

cart sub total doesn't appear

in Safari it won't go to the guest checkout page, asks to "create an account" but in Chrome works fine.

Some products are showing a "special price" which is the amount less the tax - but others are fine.

I think all relate to the below warnings during migration?

Some of these issues appear after the first reindex, but you need to do the reindex.

Errors:

An error that I was surprised to get was customer_entity.telephone was missing from source.

I set an ignore in the map-customer.xml.dist but the downside is the telephone number on the customer account isn't migrated.

Steps taken:

Reindexed the 1.9.2.2 store and cleaned the cache

I ran the database repair tool against a reference database to ensure consistency.

I have tested to see if it's the environment; for example on the same server setup a new store with sample data and these issues don't exist.

Logs:

```
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_product
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_datetime
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_decimal
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_int
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_text
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_varchar
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_relation
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_super_attribute
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_super_attribute_label
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_super_link
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_website
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cataloginventory_stock_item
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cataloginventory_stock_status
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_event
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_viewed_product_index
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_address
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_item
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_item_option
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_payment
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoiced_aggregated
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoiced_aggregated_order
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_aggregated_created
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_aggregated_updated
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipping_aggregated
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipping_aggregated_order
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: tax_order_aggregated_created
[2015-12-06 08:38:49][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: tax_order_aggregated_updated
```

Any help would be appreciated ! Even just direction on how to diagnose. 
Have also posted on GitHub, but haven't had a response yet, hoping someone from this community can help.

Answer (score 2):

My various issues were solved by:

1. Removing all non standard fields and tables prior to migration (rather than excluding via MAP.xml.dist)
2. Removed all un-used "attributes", product & customer.
3. I didn't realize that ALL of `core_config_data is migrated` - some of the custom modules settings were conflicting with Magento2 so I removed all of the non essential settings in this table.

All worked on Re-ran the migration tool.